# Best practice to call lambda to lambda with multi tenancy?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless

In my `Serverless` web-app (`nodeJS`) which supports multi tenancy, I have the following architecture:

- Layer of controller - each controller is a lambda function (separated repository)
- Layer of service - each service is a lambda function (another separated repository) which also calling to Dynamo DB.

Currently the controller is calling the service lambda using http (development purposes only) and we want to make it better using aws-sdk  with `lambda.invoke()` or Step functions.

In case that we will use `lambda.invoke()`, there is a need to have a stable ARN per each lambda function and use it over other lambda's.

My question is, how can I have an ARN per each tenant+lambda and how can I maintain it?

In other case which we will use step functions, I wanted to know if its suitable for this kind of architecture ?

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to maintain the lambda ARN if you know where to look for the current one. You can use an export from a CloudFormation deck or ssm parameter or DynamoDB or anything really. Even for the step function you can redeploy with using the CloudFormation output exports and it will point to the correct ARNs.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "know where to look for the current one" ?

Comment: I mean - you do not have to know the ARN of the lambda in the time of the deployment if you are able to look-up the current one dynamically.

Comment: dynamically how ? is there any API for that ?

Comment: I mean, just store it somewhere - like ssm parameter and pick it up before the call, If you have too many calls you can cache it for a few seconds.